# Get Textview from Collapsingtoolbarlayout

Tags: android, textview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, shared-element-transition

Im currently trying to get the title from collapsingtoolbarlayout as textview. I want to do an shared element transition between an item in a recyclerview in a previous activity. The title from the item in the recyclerview should be translated to my collapsingtoolbarlayout title.

In activity A i have a recyclerview with that list layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/row_container"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#282828"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_top"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And the @id/title should animate to the collapsingtoolbarlayout title of this activity B:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="28dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="20dp"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:transitionName="toolbar_image"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#252525"
    >
    ...
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you figure it out? I have been looking for a solution to this.

Comment: @ShahiM Nope, dont think its possible currently.

Comment: @ShahiM @Muffin `CollapsingToolbarLayout` doesnt have a `TextView`, it has `CollapsingTextHelper` with `TextPaint`

Answer (score 0):

1. Read about intents from the Android developers page or any tutorial online.
2. Create an intent to the new activity on the click of RecyclerView item in the previous activity.
3. Use `.putExtra()` to transmit the name of the item as a string through the intent
4. In the new activity `onCreate()` method, use:

```
    .getStringExtra()

    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title_name");

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    tv.setText(title);
```

This is a generic code. Modify accordingly.

I hope this is what you required.

Comment: This is how i transfer data between activities. But i want to do an animation between the two textviews. Its called "Shared Element Transition".

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that. Learnt a new thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your item is:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        ...
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the Detail Activity:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
     <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout
            ...
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <Toolbar
            android:title=""
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <TextView
                    ...
                    android:transitionName="@string/transition_name"/>

            </Toolbar>
        </CollpasingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>

    <RecyclerView
        ...
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here the catch is transitionName element which is common property in both the activity's TextView, and both the names should be same. That is all for the XML work.

In Java,

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);

View sharedView = textview;
String transitionName = getString(R.string.transition_name);

ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, sharedView, transitionName);
startActivity(i, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
```

Please refer to the best documentation in detail here:

https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

Comment: but then i cant use my collapsingtoolbarlayout anymore :/ i really want to use it. I dont know how i should do this with collapsingtoolbarlayout, with the textview, that is moving like the title from collapsingtoolbarlayout.

Comment: @Muffin You mean to say something like Whatsapp's Friend's profile Activity?

Comment: not really. i want to animate a textview from activity a, in an  item from recyclerview, to the title from collapsingtoolbarlayout in activity b ^^

Comment: but how do i let the textview be working and moving like the title in collapsingtoolbarlayout?

Comment: @Muffin Please clear your doubt with an example atleast.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've looked into the collapsing toolbar code, being it only a wrapper for toolbar, and the `setTitle()` function it has, it only sets a `collapsingtexthelper` which implements a `charsequence`, and uses it to display in a view in the layout.

There is no `textview` as far as I have seen in the code.